# Kafka MQTT Sink Connector fails with HashMap is not a supported type

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

Here is my Kafka-MQTT Sink Connector config

```
name=anonymous
confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers= localhost:9092
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSinkConnector
confluent.topic.replication.factor=1
tasks.max=1
mqtt.server.uri=tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
topics=mqtt
```

When I run Kafka-connect it fails with this message

```
    [2021-07-22 17:35:37,565] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=anonymous-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: java.util.HashMap is not a supported type. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:612)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.util.HashMap is not a supported type.
    at io.confluent.connect.mqtt.SinkConverter.convert(SinkConverter.java:39)
    at io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSinkTask.put(MqttSinkTask.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The Kafka-MQTT version is 1.4.1 Any pointers where it is getting wrong?

Comment: Last I checked, the MQTT connector only supported data of bytes/strings. Please show what data you're sending

Comment: I have jsonConverter in my Kafka connect configuration and I am using json data

Comment: For both the key and value? Or only the value? Did you add a config of `value.converter.schemas.enable=false`? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it works after replacing JsonConverter with StringConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you default key/value converters , how do you start your kafka connect? Share your connect config file , what values do you have on value/key converters

Try adding this configuration definition

```
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
```

Comment: I have JsonConverter for both key & value in Kafka connect configuration.

Comment: same error changed JsonConverter to StingConverter

Comment: My bad, it works, I had JsoNConverter at 2 places. So only StringConverter works.